# Play Framework - inheritence

Tags: inheritance, playframework

My models - Question, and Answer, extend a class Post. Post has a field - String content.

Let question be an instance of class Question. My HTML contains question.content, but raises an exception, saying the field can't be found. Why doesn't question have the inherited 'content' field?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you forget to post your model?

Comment: How does the rest of the model matter? My concern is with the fields I defined in the parent class which should have been inherited in the child classes (models). Just to clear it up, Question and Answer are models (entities), but not Post.

Comment: Code samples, stack trace... A bit of an effort gets you a long way!

Answer (score 2):

You need to annotate your super class with `@MappedSuperclass`.

If you look at the source code for 'play.db.jpa.Model' which I assume your entities inherit from, you will see this special annotation used. This brings the content of this class into your persisted entities.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still get the same exception!

Comment: need more info to be posted. Try adding your classes and exceptions to the question, which may lead to a little more insight.